# Verifing that $f$ is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, functions

$f:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to \Bbb R$ be given by
$$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
xy^2,  & \ y\lt x^2 \\
x+2y, & \ y\ge x^2
\end{cases}$$

I need to show that $f$ is integrable. My idea is that to show $Dincont(f)\subseteq S={(x,y): y=x^2}$. If $S$ is measure $0$, $\implies$ discontinuities of $f$ is also measure $0$. The it would mean that $f$ is integrable. Can someone please give me a hint about how to show that $S$ is measure $0$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you mean $3n+1$ when $y \ge x^2$ and not something at least involving $x$ and or $y$? Otherwise why not replace $3n+1$ by something like $C$?

Comment: @coffeemath oh sorry. I typed wrongly. I edited it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $y=x^2$ in $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ can be shown to have measure zero if it can be contained in sets of arbitrarily small measure. So divide up each axis into $n$ parts, getting a grid with $n^2$ boxes each of area $1/n^2.$ The part needed to cover the graph of $y=x^2$ is bounded by a constant times $n$, say $kn$, so the area needed to cover the parabola is at most $kn/n^2=k/n,$ which can be made arbitrarily small.

That $k=3$ here works can be seen by noting that, above each interval $I_j=[(j-1)/n,j/n]$ for $1\le j \le n$ the graph of $y=x^2$ can cut through at most three of the vertically stacked squares of sidelength $1/n$ which lie above interval $I.$ This is dependent on the max slope of $y=x^2$ being $2$ in the interval $[0,1].$

Note: As outlined in a comment, the "max vertical boxes $3$" statement can be proved using the mean value theorem. For a specific case where $3$ vertical boxes are actually needed, consider $n=10$ and the interval $[.8,.9]$ with the squared endpoints $.64,\ .81.$ In this case the curve $y=x^2$ enters each of the three vertically aligned boxes in $[.8,.9] \times [.6,.9].$

Comment: why do you conclude that the boxes cover y=x2 is bounded by a constant times n? Can you elaborate that please?

Comment: There are $n$ stacks of boxes over each of the $n$ subintervals $I_j$ and, since the slope of $y=x^2$ is at most $2$ on $[0,1],$ at most three boxes over each $I_j$ can be crossed by the graph of $y=x^2$. This gives the bound of $3n$ for the number of boxes to cover the graph. [If the graph covered 4 vertical boxes, then by the mean value theorem the slope would need to be at least $3$ somewhere between the ends.]

Comment: How is the slope of the function related the number of boxes that it can pass? Is there such a theorem?

Comment: I do not understand it

Comment: If the graph covers 4 boxes, then from the left side to the right of that box it has gone up at least 3 box-widths while going to the right only one box width. Thus the slope of the segment joining the two places on $y=x^2$ over that part would be at least $3$. The mean value theorem says (roughly) that if $\Delta y/\Delta x=k$ over some interval, then $y'(c)=k$ for some value of $c$ between the interval endpoints. (If you don't already know the mean value theorem, it's useful to know, and likely google can get youstarted with it.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience :) I got it

Comment: @CaptainFlint No problem. I find it interesting to use the mean value theorem in cases like this, to make precise an intuitive feeling. At first I thought the graph would only cross at most two boxes vertically aligned, but later thought about the case of steep lines which cross a lot of vertical boxes in not much horizontal length. Then how to show at most 3 boxes for $y=x^2$ with the derivative bound of $2$, suggested the mean value theorem as a method to prove it.